# Snowflake BLANK_IF?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

Is there a way to load a particular value as blank or empty string in Snowflake.
For example, I have hex value x98 written in the file which represents blank, and I want to load this value in the column as an empty string (e.g. '').

Comment: Are you trying to do this as part of your COPY command?

Answer (score 0):

[NULLIF()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif.html) might be what you're after. Takes 2 values ... if they're equal then returns null. Other functions used  [HEX_DECODE_STRING()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hex_decode_string.html) [HEX_ENCODE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hex_encode.html)

```
select 
 NULLIF('Snowflake',HEX_DECODE_STRING('536E6F77666C616B65'))
,HEX_ENCODE('Snowball')
```

[image]

Side note there's not HEX to INT in snowflake but here's a [link](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/faq-does-snowflake-have-a-hex-to-int-type-function) to showing you a simple UDF to do the conversion. As [0098 hex -> 152 decimal](https://www.hexdictionary.com/hex/0098) you might be better doing this first?